# SQL Server 2008 ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

My SQL Server 2008 is located on a remote computer so I am trying to create an ODBC connection using SQL Server Authentication.

My problem is that the way i normally connect to my SQL Server is by doing a remote desktop connection and then I just connect using windows authentication so I don't know what my SQL Server Username and Password are.

Is there anyway I can find out what my Sql Server Authentication username is so I can maybe reset my password?

All I am trying to do is to create an ODBC connection usnig SQL Server Authentication since I can't use Windows Authentication since the SQL Server is on a remote Windows Server computer (or can I?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the Database Administrator for the environment what your SQL Server Login details are for using SQL Server Authentication.

Alternatively, you could connect to the SQL Server Instance via RDP and Windows Authentication and then create a new SQL Server Login for you to use remotely.

To confirm, you cannot use Windows authentication remotely (from outside of the domain the instance resides in) unless you are connecting from a domain with a trust relationship defined.

Answer (score 1):

if your windows user has sysadmin privilege> login to your server as you do and after you login to your sql server using SSMS, go to security>logins>sa
double click on sa and reset your password

[image: Reset SA password]